# In Angular, how to compile [routerLink] on a content obtained from an API before adding the content to website?

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular, how would I compile a content sent through an API, similar to what $compile does in Angular 1.x, so I can get any possible routerLinks (or ngFor, ngIf, etc) working properly?

In other words, suppose that I get a content from an API which contains links based on routerLink. How can I compile that content so when I insert it into the website it will have the links functioning properly?

Example:

```
{
  "title": "My post",
  "content": "My link: <a [routerLink]=\"['about','123']\"">About</a>"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would always have your return be split into elements that can be individual components,  but in the real world this is probably not always possible.

I had a similar issue where I wanted my api response html to be compiled, rendered, interpolated etc.  The only solution I have found uses `compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync` to compile a new module and component on the fly for a sort of dynamic component. 
It goes like :

```
// First you need few modules loaded like Compiler

import { Component, NgModule, Compiler, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

// You need a place to load your dynamic content     
// put <div #spot/> in the html you will be loading content into
@ViewChild('spot', {read: ViewContainerRef}) spot: ViewContainerRef;

// Remember to add them to the constructor
constructor(private compiler: Compiler , private route: ActivatedRoute 
...

// On the get event from your API.
this.someservice.get(someid).subscribe(data => {
    this.tmpComponent(this.data[0].someHtml);
...


// Then in your method, you create a new component
private tmpComponent(tpl: string) {

  @Component({
     selector: 'some-tpl',
     template: tpl
  })
  class TmpComponent {
  }

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
      TmpComponent
    ],
    exports: [
      TmpComponent
    ]
  })
  class TmpModule {
  }

  var mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TmpModule);
  var factory = mod.componentFactories.find((c) => c.componentType === TmpComponent);
  this.spot.createComponent(factory);

}
```

Comment: Thank you Dylan, your solution works! On the last line, I believe that you meant to put this.spot.createComponent(factory), instead of container. Correct?

Comment: yes, oops, (I edited it), I was kind of refactoring my own project at the same time ;)

Comment: This method works perfectly for JIT compilation but fails for AOT giving error `Runtime compiler is not loaded`. are you people able to make it work in AOT build?